# How to share data between two component in angular?

Tags: angular

Here I have two components(named as first and second component) I want to share data between this two component, In first component I have userid this userid I want to fetch in second component so I tried to fetch using service but in second component userid is get undefined(in service i get userid perfectly see console but in second component userid get undefined), so how to get userid in second component ?

user.service.ts

```
  useridOfuser;

  getUserData(){ 
    console.log(this.userid) // 98
    return this.userid; 
  }

  setUserData(userid){
    console.log(userid);  // 98
    this.useridOfuser= userid;
  }
```

first.component.ts

```
  constructor(private userService : UserService,private route : ActivatedRoute) {
     const userid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('userid'); // 98
    this.userService.setUserData(userid);
  }
```

second.component.ts

```
 constructor(private userService : UserService);
 userid;

 ngOnInit() {
   this.userid = this.userService.getUserData();
   console.log(this.userid);  // undefined
 }
```

Comment: The second component is rendered before the first one, that's why. How do you want to share this data, and how this components are rendered?

Comment: in first component one button click on that button it is route on second component so i want to send this userid in second component

Comment: @Ankit where did you provide user.service ?

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan what i not understand?

Comment: @Ankit : in first component you are getting `userId` from your route parameter, whereas in second component you try to get `userId` from your service.

Comment: @Ankit I meant where do you add your service in providers array, in module or in both components ?

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan in app.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service is generally a working idea. However, it might be that your second component call `this.userService.getUserData();` before you call `this.userService.setUserData(userid);` in the first component. 
For this, i would recommend to a reactive pattern. Reactive programming is one of the core concepts of angular.

So, your userService should somehow look like this.

```
useridOfuser = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);

  getUserData(): Observable<number> { 
    console.log(this.userid) // 98
    return this.useridOfuser; 
  }

  setUserData(userid:number) {
    console.log(userid);  // 98
    this.useridOfuser.next(userid);
  }
```

in the component2, you can subscribe to the userId.
second.component.ts

```
 constructor(private userService : UserService);
 userid;

 ngOnInit() {
   this.userService.getUserData()
   .subscribe(userId => this.userid = userId); // Will update when it changes
   console.log(this.userid);  // undefined
 }
```

I hoped, this helped you!

Junus

Comment: ur answer is works, I got userid in second component now when i refresh browser that time in second component I get userid null, but I want userid permanently if i refresh browser

Comment: In that case you have to save the number in your web browser. you could use localStorage for this.
E.g. you could do something like this:
setUserData(userid:number) {
    console.log(userid);  // 98
    localStorage.setItem('userid', userid);
    this.useridOfuser.next(userid);
  }

add to your constructor() {
   const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
   if(userId)  {
       this.useridIfuser.next()
    }
}